# 2013SP online - find all urls for each of the documents on site

Tags: 2013

I have a SP site that houses about 10,000 documents. I need to find a quick way to have this kind of report:

Document title   /   Document url   /   DocumentID

I need to create a quick link for about 500 of the documents...I would prefer them to open automatically in the online version of either Word or Excel by default. I can get the links in SP Designer, but those open the file locally in the desktop application. I can't imagine going to every single file in the web browser just to copy that url and then turn that into a friendly link page.

Please help - I'm fairly new at this, but I have to get this done today...ARGH!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get the big list of 500 URLs through SharePoint Designer, which it sounds like you are able to do, there is a trick you can use to make them open in the OWA (Office Web Apps) application instead of the desktop application.

Where the URL looks like /mydocument1.docx or /mydocument2.xslx, change them to /mydocument1.docx?Web=1 or /mydocument2.xslx?Web=1.  It should be fairly simple to append this to the end of your list or URLs in Excel.

This might not solve your whole problem, but hopefully it helps a little.